# Распарсить ответ ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть функция

```
 $.ajax({
            url: ur,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (e) {

            }
        });
```

в `e` я получаю разметку страницы целиком, мне нужно в `success` вытащить один div и вывести его на сайт. Как из `e` его получить?

Comment: 1) настроить `ur` так, чтобы он сразу возвращал сразу нужный кусок кода; 2) парсить `$(e)`; 3) использовать http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @br3t так как распарсить е?

Comment: `так как распарсить е` - а что возвращается с сервера? То и парсите. `console.log(e)` и  в путь

Comment: @СергейМишин все, разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у Вас возвращается в e такой html:

```
<div>
    <div class="myClass">...</div>
    <div id="my-id">
       ...
    </div>
    <p>...</p>
    ...
</div>
```

Вам нужно получить контент в `div` с id `my-id`, тогда можно попробовать так:

```
var result = $('<div />').append(e).find('#my-id').html();
```

Comment: да я find`ом и сделал спасибо

Comment: Можно и  `$(e).find('#my-id')`